# SQL how to get values from diffrent tables?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Connection

```
_id  NAME   SERVER_IP   SERVER_PORT TOPIC   QOS
  1  home   192.168.1.102   1883    test     0
  2  home2  192.168.1.102   1800    test2    0
```

and Online:

```
_id  ONLINE
  1  false
  2  false
```

When I do query

```
String rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM connection,online";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
           rawQuery,
           null
 );
dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String connection_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBase.BaseEntry.CONNECTION_NAME));
            String online = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBase.ServiceEntry.ONLINE));
            dataModels.add(new DataModel(connection_name, online));
        }
```

I get multiplied output, like : home false, home2 false, home false, home2 false. How can I make correct request and get simple output like : home false, home2 false?

Comment: Modify your sql that it does not return duplicates - If you use a sql client to test out your sql you will see that you get duplicates.  May I suggest that you use a JOIN for a start.

Comment: Seems you are asking us to teach you SQL or to write your SQL for you. If you don't know how to write a SQL `JOIN`, then it's time for you to grab you SQL Guide and **learn SQL**.

Comment: You need to join the tables

Using a `FULL OUTER JOIN` , `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, or `INNER JOIN` (I'll let you look up the difference).

Assuming that you only want to info that's in both, we'll use an `INNER JOIN` in this query  

      
`SELECT * FROM connection AS c INNER JOIN online AS o ON c._id = o._id;`

Using the AS after the table name gives it an alias which makes reading the query a lot easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM connection INNER JOIN online ON connection._id=online._id;
```

was trying to query it but, the problem was that I was using `_id=_id`